# Find all possible cominations of strings from n string arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, combinations

I have the following unknown number of arrays

```
var sizes = ["8", "9", "10"];
var colors = ["Black", "Blue"];
var laces = ["Yes", "No"];
....
....
upto n array
```

I have a case where i have to find all the possible combinations of all strings in these arrays

for example :

```
var combinations = [["8", "Black", "Yes", ...], ["9", "Black", "Yes", ...], ...];
```

---

[This is the best answer Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53311986/8766958)

Comment: There is also this [all-possible-combinations-of-a-2d-array-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53311809/all-possible-combinations-of-a-2d-array-in-javascript)

Comment: I think this will be your answer please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/57015870/15320376

Comment: i m verifying all the comments please wait  

Comment: @pavlovic265 thats the best answer i think. thank you guys. the way i was searching couldnt load those answers else i would just have looked into them. thank you again